# How do I find users who haven't opened any bulk mail from me recently?

Tags: civimail, custom-search

Bounce handling is broken on my site, and so I'm trying to clean my list through several steps.

I'd like to get a list of users who have not opened *any* mailings in the recent past (say six months).

I keep getting a server error 500 when I try to use the advanced search > mailings tab. But also I suspect that this search will simply give me a list of all contacts who have ever failed to open an email in the recent past, as opposed to the contacts who have never opened any emails.
[image: Mailing tab settings used in advanced contact search]

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running CiviCRM 4.6.14 integrated with a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to use the Custom Search of Include/Exclude and make a Group that includes those who have opened, so you can 'exclude' them from a search of all possible recipients.

Comment: This sounds good, but I get a server error whenever I try to do the first search!

Comment: can you replicate that on demo site?

Comment: thanks - I'd be happy to try, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that without uploading all my contacts. I'm open to any guidance.

Comment: i meant try to replicate the 'first search' you are doing locally - and see if you get a server error on the demo site. but perhaps i am not really following. sorry

Comment: Sure, I tried searching by restricting to a group plus, in the Mailings section, restricting by date (this calendar year) and "opened." The search was fast and produced no matches.